# Charles showing Blocked status with unknown

Tags: charles-proxy

> I have tried by uninstall and installation of Charles but getting same issue, Getting blocked status for all request laptop, emulator , real phone. previously it is working.
> Please check below screenshots for the same.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by disabling the Allow list
Tools>>Allow List

[image]

[image]